# Error when compile cuda with ptx instruction 'ldmatrix' and 'mma'

Tags: cmake, cuda, ptx

I got error from the following code when I intended to use `ldmatrix` and `mma` instruction. PTX Docu says that 'ldmatrix' is introduced in PTX 6.5. So I doubt the the PTX version could be one reason. I'd like to know how do we find out which PTX version are we using? What other possibilities could be the reason for those errors?

```cpp
    __device__ void
    runldmatrix(typet & D, unsigned addr){
      #if (defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) && (__CUDA_ARCH__ >= 750))
        int x, y, z, w;            
        asm volatile (
          "ldmatrix.sync.aligned.x4.m8n8.shared.b16 {%0, %1, %2, %3}, [%4];" 
          : "=r"(x), "=r"(y), "=r"(z), "=r"(w) 
          : "r"(addr));             
        reinterpret_cast<int4 &>(D) = make_int4(x, y, z, w);
      #else
        assert(0);
      #endif
    }

    __device__  void
    runmma(typet & d, typet const & a, 
                typet  const & b,typet const & c ){
                  
#if (defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) && (__CUDA_ARCH__ >= 750))                  
        unsigned const *A = reinterpret_cast<unsigned const *>(&a);
        unsigned const & B = reinterpret_cast<unsigned const &>(b);
        unsigned const *C = reinterpret_cast<unsigned const *>(&c);
        unsigned *D = reinterpret_cast<unsigned *>(&d);
        
          asm volatile(
              "mma.sync.aligned.m16n8k8.row.col.f16.f16.f16.f16 {%0,%1}, {%2,%3}, {%4}, {%5,%6};\n"
              : "=r"(D[0]), "=r"(D[1])
              : "r"(A[0]), "r"(A[1]), "r"(B), "r"(C[0]), "r"(C[1]));
#endif    
    }
```

> /tmp/tmpxft_00002eb6_00000000-5_test_gemm.ptx, line 2637; error   :
> Unknown modifier '.x4' ptxas

> /tmp/tmpxft_00002eb6_00000000-5_test_gemm.ptx, line 2637; error   :
> Unknown modifier '.m8n8' ptxas

> /tmp/tmpxft_00002eb6_00000000-5_test_gemm.ptx, line 2637; error   :
> Not a name of any known instruction: 'ldmatrix'

ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_000

> 02ee1_00000000-5_test_gemm.ptx, line 2611; error   : Unknown modifier
> '.m16n8k8' ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_00002ee1_00000000-5_test_gemm.ptx, line
> 2611; error   : Shape modifier required for instruction 'mma'

update:

I'm using 2080 Ti with CUDA 10.1, with the following cmake to ensure the computation ability of 7.5

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(Hello)
enable_language(CUDA)

add_executable(gunne test_gemm.cu)
target_include_directories(gunne PRIVATE include)
set_property(TARGET gunne PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 75)
```

Comment: You need to specify an appropriate architecture for the features you wish to use to the compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Docu says that 'ldmatrix' is introduced in PTX 6.5. So I doubt the the PTX version could be one reason.

> What other possibilities could be the reason for those errors?

Actually, that is the reason.  CUDA 10.1 (the most recent version of it) included PTX version 6.4.

If you search [the PTX manual that shipped with that version of CUDA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.1/parallel-thread-execution/index.html), there is no `ldmatrix` instruction.

Furthermore, if we look at the [relevant section](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.1/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#warp-level-matrix-instructions-wmma-mma) we observe that there is no `m16n8k8` variant in that PTX version, for the `mma.sync.aligned` instruction.

It seems that all of your compile errors collapse down to these issues.  When I provide a definition for `typet` (and `#include <cassert>`) the code will compile for me on e.g. CUDA 11.4

> I'd like to know how do we find out which PTX version are we using?

I can think of at least a couple ways, there are probably others.

An "offline" method is: Assuming you are using a CUDA Version of 8.0 or newer, go to the [cuda docs page](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html), select [the PTX manual](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html), then notice at the top the notation:

PTX ISA (PDF) - v11.5.1 (older)

Click the [older](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) link, and it will take you to a page where you can select the versioned online documentation that corresponds to your CUDA version. Then select the PTX manual there, and it will indicate what version it is for.

An alternative method would be to compile any CUDA code using your toolchain to PTX (e.g. `nvcc my_kernel_code.cu --ptx` and study the resultant ptx file.   Near the top it will have a notation like:

```
.version 7.4
```

This will tell you the PTX version your toolchain is generating.

I'm not suggesting your code is otherwise correct, merely that it can/will compile when using a suitable toolchain.  You haven't provided a complete code, nor stated your intent, so I see no real point in going beyond this, but the usage of `int` variables with the `.b16` instruction doesn't make much sense to me.  It appears to compile, however.

Comment: Thans for the wonderful answer. I switched to 11.3 and the code compiles well for me. For your feedback, actually the code is picked from [link](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cutlass/blob/808c25337a3ed4c97ac21895257b1addc72d6ca8/include/cutlass/arch/memory_sm75.h#L194). I haven't dug deeper into it :)